# Como alterar formato de data no bootstrap de mm/dd/yyyy para dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

Esse é o erro que está dando:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pt-BR' of undefined

Inserir alguns links para formatar a data, segunto tuto que peguei na net e mesmo assim a data continua errada(outro formato) e tenho esse erro(citado acima) na página. E tem mais, quando eu seleciono a data, ela vai para o textbox, porem o calendário continua aparecendo, somente se eu clicar em outro lugar é que ele some. Já coloquei esses três links:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" ></script>
```

Veja como estão meus jquery e js. Acho que tem coisa demais.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />    
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>        
<link href="~/Content/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eu tive este problema, editei o original e transformei em pt-br

Comment: @pnet se ta fazendo isso pelo mvc asp.net no visual studio neh ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**É só colocar essa `language: 'pt-BR'`**

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                
    language: 'pt-BR'
});
```

***Baixe pelo Site***

- [Datepicker for Bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

***Baixe pelo Visual Studio via `Manage Nuget Packages`***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Utilize exemplo abaixo na mesma sequencia dos `css`, `js`.

***Exemplo:***

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Data</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker-globalize.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                
                language: 'pt-BR'
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <input type="text" name="data" class="datepicker" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Exemplo On-Line***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não precisou os includes, apenas a função jquery e resolveu com emus includes. Obrigado.

Comment: Blz @pnet, é que nós temos que pensar que isso pode e vai servir para muita gente, entendeu !!!

Comment: ok, harry, entendi.

Answer (score 1):

Pode não ser uma boa prática, mas ao invés de ficar adicionando outros arquivos JS.
Eu editei o arquivo original e mantive as referências do criador do plugin.

Dá uma olhada, se achar conveniente, copie a vontade, não precisa ficar adicionando mais nada, nem editar o css original.

https://gist.github.com/aymone/eb135c65f4f32fda8c9c

Outra coisa, caso precise adicionar mais locales, ele continua funcionando em outros idiomas, mas como meu projeto era exclusivamente pt-br, me atendeu perfeitamente e carrega até mais rápido, porque não precisa baixar mais um js com a tradução.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja acontecendo por conta da ordem das importações, tente importar nesta ordem:

1) datepicker.css

2) bootstrap-datepicker.js

3) bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.js

Comment: o jquery e o bootstrap.js vem antes desses 3 arquivos?

Comment: o jquery é requirido para os plugins do bootstrap ... http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: então, tenho tido em outra tela algum erro dizendo que falta o jquery. Pode serv isso. Qual jquery eu utilizo para isso? Veja minha edição.

Comment: No exemplo do template que eu postei o cara usa a versão 1.11 ... mas acredito que isso vá depender dos plugins que vc for utilizar ...
 
O seu plugin acredito que seja esse: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker

e eles usam a versão 1.9.1 do jquery, mas nada impede de vc usar uma versão mais atual e testar...

Comment: Então, baixei o cara e veio uma pasta com vários arquivos e pastas. O que faço agora? Como eu adiciono? Adiciono tudo no meu projeto?

Comment: Mas o erro de javascript continua, ainda que funcionando o formato, mas continua não fechando o calendário.